# Can't click button under tab menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I created one activity under tab menu. In that activity if I click button it direct to the another activity under the same tab, this activity contains the some edit text and buttons. In that I can not click or perform some action when clicking the button.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View v) {
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_registration);
     Intent intent = new Intent(SongsActivity.this,FiveActivity.class);
               } });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
     setContentView(R.layout.contact_registration);
     Intent intent = new Intent(SongsActivity.this,ContactregistrationActivity.class);
 } 
 });
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I am a little lost. If you want to start a new activity with the pressing of the button you have to add in your listener after your intent initiator a `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: yes good but it starts a new activity. i want to starts under the same tab menu.

Comment: i change the description please see...

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an Intent and then doing nothing with it.

Add the line `startActivity(intent)` at the end of each onCLick method to start the activity.

Comment: if i use start activity it shows a activity in a new window but i want   under the same menu it should start.

Comment: In that case you need to learn about Fragments https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: i can get activity under the tab menu but i cant perform any button action why?